# How to count all the items in the python list without using loops

Tags: python

How to count all the items in the python list

```
board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]

print(len(board)) #prints 9 as the length of list
```

How do I print all the available items in the list (91) (without using any loop)

Comment: What is your expected output? By "print all the available items", do you literally mean `7, 8, 0, ...`?

Comment: Assuming your matrix is rectangular, `print(len(board) * len(board[0]))`.

Comment: `sum(len(row) for row in board)` results in 81 (9 x 9) and allows for irregular shaped boards.

Comment: You can do this with a reduction, but before using Higher-order functions perhaps you may want to give a bit more context on your question.

Comment: @Alexander doesn't that have a `for` in there?

Comment: @Firafun shouldn't the output be `81` instead of `91`?

Comment: @norok2 I would classify it as a generator expression rather than a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the list, and then count and print it normally -

```
print(len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(board))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), e.g.:

```
import functools


board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]


length = functools.reduce(lambda total, item: total + len(item), board, 0)
print(length)
# 81
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools 

arr_len = functools.reduce(lambda a,b : len(a)+len(b),board))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(list(map(len,board)))
```

works as well

output:

```
81
```